# What does an empty set of parentheses mean when used in a generic type declaration?

Tags: rust

The `Display` trait is defined as follows:

```
pub trait Display {
    fn fmt(&self, &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error>;
}
```

The most mysterious thing to me is the empty set of parentheses, `()`, in the type declaration `Result<(), Error>`. What is it and its purpose?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`()` is an empty tuple, a simple zero-sized type (it uses no memory) with only one value possible, `()`. It’s also known as the *unit type*. Its use in a return type of `Result<(), E>` means “if nothing goes wrong, there’s no further value produced”. The semantics are what’s important—the call was OK.

`Result<(), ()>` would also make sense as a return type—either something succeeded, or it failed, with nothing more to report in either case.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  Seems analogous to `void`.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @w.brian: It is indeed analogous to `void`, but `void` requires special cases to handle (especially in C++ where you can `return foo()` where `foo` returns `void` but cannot create a value of `void` type...), so in this sense `()` is just so much more streamlined.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think this answer is missing a little explanation: the definition of `Result`. Not everyone is familiar with `Result`, so your explanation "if nothing goes wrong, there's no further value produced" may not be understandable.