# How to return a struct with the unit data type?

Tags: generics, struct, syntax, rust, tuples

I am trying to implement a custom set. This can be compiled with no problems:

```
struct CustomSet {}

impl CustomSet {
    pub fn new() -> CustomSet {
        CustomSet {}
    }
}
```

When I tried to add unit type (empty tuple) into the `CustomSet` type, it won't compile.

```
struct CustomSet<()> {}

impl CustomSet<()> {
    pub fn new() -> CustomSet<()> {
        CustomSet {}
    }
}
```

Error with the following

```
error: expected one of `>`, identifier, or lifetime, found `(`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:18
  |
1 | struct CustomSet<()> {}
  |                  ^ expected one of `>`, identifier, or lifetime here
```

How to return a struct with the unit data type? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you want a generic struct like `struct CustomSet <T>`?

Comment: "unit data type" what is it ?

Comment: Generic struct will force me to implement custom `T` type and rust compiler will complain that type `T` is unused on the struct.

Comment: "unit data type" is just an empty tuple `()`. I found it on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107614/what-does-an-empty-set-of-parentheses-mean-when-used-in-a-generic-type-declarati?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have to use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html)

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct CustomSet<T> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl CustomSet<()> {
    pub fn new() -> CustomSet<()> {
        CustomSet {
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

The PhantomData "informs" the  compiler that the argument `T` is used and so it will no longer complain about that.

Note that although you add a member to your struct, it will not consume any more size.

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<CustomSet<()>>());  // 0
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<CustomSet<u32>>()); // 0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The type `CustomSet<()>` only makes sense if `CustomSet` is defined with a type parameter. A type parameter is a variable, not another type, so your definition doesn't really make sense. Rather, you need to define it with a variable:

```
struct CustomSet<T> {}
```

This means that `CustomSet` is defined for any possible type `T` (with the caveat that the type must be `Sized`, which is true of most types).

Now, the definition above won't work as it is because Rust will complain that you are not using the variable `T` inside the type. What's the point of a variable you don't use?

As [hellow said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52001525/493729), you could use `PhantomData`, but that is more of a workaround for when you need the variable but don't actually need to use it for some reason. Since you are implementing a collection, you will want to use the `T` in order to store values somewhere:

```
struct CustomSet<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
}
```

The behaviour of this type can still be implemented for *all possible* `T`, not just `()`, giving you lots of code reuse:

```
impl<T> CustomSet<T> {
    pub fn new() -> CustomSet<T> {
        CustomSet {
            data: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

It's only when you actually use the type that you need to constrain `T` at all:

```
let my_set: CustomSet<()> = CustomSet::new();
```

Even that type annotation would often not be needed in a real program, as it would be inferred from usage. For example, if you had provided an `insert` method for `CustomSet`, you might use it like this:

```
// type annotation not needed because it will be inferred from the next line
let mut my_set = CustomSet::new();
my_set.insert(());
```