# What is a memory-efficient type for a map with no meaningful value in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Go, a memory-efficient way of storing values you want to retrieve by key that has no associated value is to use a map of empty structs keyed with the data you want to store. For instance, if you have a list of strings you want to check have been previously seen by your program, you could do something like this:

```golang
var seen = map[string]struct{}{}

for _, str := range strings {

 if _, ok := seen[str]; ok {
  // do something
 } else {
  seen[str] = struct{}{}
 }

}
```

Is there a Rust equivalent to this? I am aware that Rust doesn't have anonymous structs like Go, so what Rust type would use the least amount of memory in a map like the above example? Or is there a different, more idiomatic approach?

Comment: It sounds like you want a [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html)?

Comment: Are you looking for a [set](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html)? Does Go really not have that?

Comment: Even if sets didn't exist in Rust, a memory efficient, trivial type is the empty set: `()`.

Comment: Implying that you need anonymous structs to create empty memory-efficient values strikes me as odd. Rust has many unit types you can use (`()` being the most trivial one), but set collection types are also readily available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) is [defined as](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.39.0/src/libstd/collections/hash/set.rs#L111-L113) a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) with the unit tuple as the value:

```
pub struct HashSet<T, S = RandomState> {
    map: HashMap<T, (), S>,
}
```

The [same is true](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.39.0/src/liballoc/collections/btree/set.rs#L61-L63) for [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) / [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html):

```
pub struct BTreeSet<T> {
    map: BTreeMap<T, ()>,
}
```

> what Rust type would use the least amount of memory

Any type with only one possible value uses zero bytes. `()` is an easy-to-type one.

See also:

- [What does an empty set of parentheses mean when used in a generic type declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31107614/155423)